# ORA-12504:TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: oracle, weblogic, listener, tnsnames, sid

I'm new to oracle and trying to start a web application using oracle weblogic.
The application works ok but I am consistently having this error: `ORA-12504:TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA`

I've searched the web for answers and found out that this is a very common issue for newbies like me.
There's something I found from http://ora-12xyz.com/error/ORA-12504 which says that the way to solve this problem is by this:

- Configure DEFAULT_SERVICE parameter in LISTENER.ORA with a valid service name. Reload the listener parameter file using reload []. This should be done by the LISTENER administrator.

but I really do not know how or where to set this on the listener.ora file.

Kindly find below my listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\saduarte\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\saduarte\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\saduarte\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MAN-L3JFGR32.misys.global.ad)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\saduarte
```

My tnsname.ora is below, in case this is also needed to solve the issue.

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\saduarte\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
TIPLUS2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MAN-L3JFGR32.misys.global.ad)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TIPLUS2)
    )
  )
```

This is what I get by executing `lsnrctl status` on cmd:

```
C:\Users\saduarte>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-FEB-2016 11:55
:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                23-FEB-2016 11:35:33
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 20 min. 10 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\saduarte\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\
listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\app\saduarte\diag\tnslsnr\MAN-L3JFGR32\listener\ale
rt\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MAN-L3JFGR32.misys.global.ad)(PORT=1
521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
Service "TIPLUS2XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tiplus2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "tiplus2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tiplus2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

And this is by executing `lsnrctl service` :

```
C:\Users\saduarte>lsnrctl service
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-FEB-2016 11:58
:29

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
      "ORACLE SERVER" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:25 state:ready
         CLRExtProc
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\NTN_1CC0_E79D7B5F.ORA))
      "ORACLE SERVER" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:25 state:ready
         CLRExtProc
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\NTN_1CC0_E79D7B5F.ORA))
Service "TIPLUS2XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tiplus2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: MAN-L3JFGR32, pid: 3052>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MAN-L3JFGR32.misys.global.ad)(PORT=61055))
Service "tiplus2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tiplus2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:58 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't have your SID declared in your listener.ora, in the SID_LIST. But you probably don't really need it. You haven't shown your connection string; if you add that to the question we can tell you how to change it - though it's probably just changing `:tiplus2` to `/tiplus2` so it uses the [service name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA) rather than the SID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. By connection string, you mean the one I declared on the **data sources >> connection pool** in weblogic? I tried changing it with what you suggested but with no luck. I have restarted the server, even my computer, but still getting ORA-12504.

Comment: Yes. What is the URL you're using for the pool; and which driver?

Comment: The details were **URL**: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@MAN-L3JFGR32:1521:TIPLUS2`
**Driver Class Name**: `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`
Thanks.

Comment: And with `jdbc:oracle:thin:@MAN-L3JFGR32:1521/TIPLUS2` you still got ORA-12504, but referring to service name rather than SID in the message text? Have you modified your listener.ora by hand? It seems to be missing an ADDRESS_LIST level, and line breaks between the sections.Have you tried running netca to reconfigure it?

Comment: Hi Alex, haven't tried any of those yet. I will try it now and give you update. Thanks alot.